# want to display data on Home screen from searched data coming from api

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield, searchbar

I am making an app in which i have a home screen which lists categories and store data into tableview. in tableview i have a search button which navigates me to search screen when clicked and on search screen i have taken custom textfield to search. Now i want that when i search something and it shows in result then when i click on searched result then it should show data of the category or store selected on previous home screen. And the search result is category data and store data. All data is coming from api and am using tableview to show search data

screenshot for coupons api in which search data will be display:
[image: coupons api]

screenshot for search api:
[image: search api]

code for my search screen is as below:

class SearchPageController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchTxtBar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var searchTblView: UITableView!

var searchData = [ModelSearched]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    searchTxtBar.delegate = self

}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

//MARK: IBActions
@IBAction func toHomeScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

func getSearchList(){

    let params: Parameters=[
        "search":searchTxtBar.text!,
    ]

    if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable()
    {
        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)
        APIClient<ModelBaseSearchList>().API_GET(Url: SD_GET_SearchList, Params: params as [String:AnyObject], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

            if(modelResponse.success == true) {

                self.searchData.removeAll()
                let resul_array_tmp_new = modelResponse.searched! as NSArray

                if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
                    for i in modelResponse.searched! {
                        self.searchData.append(i)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
            }
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.searchTblView.reloadData()
        }) { (failed) in
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.makeToast("No Internet Connection..")
    }
}

@IBAction func clearSearchData(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.searchData.removeAll()
    self.searchTxtBar.text = ""
    searchTblView.reloadData()
}
```

}

//MARK: Tableview delegates and datasource methods
extension SearchPageController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   return searchData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "catstoredata")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "catstoredata")
    }
    let dict = searchData[indexPath.row]
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none
    cell?.textLabel?.text = dict.name
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

}

//MARK: textfield delegates method
extension SearchPageController: UITextFieldDelegate{

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.searchTxtBar.resignFirstResponder()
    self.searchTblView.reloadData()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.getSearchList()

}
```

}

code for my home screen is as below:

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

```
var couponsData = [ModelCoupons]()
var colorList = [UIColor]()
var selectedIds = [Int]()

@IBOutlet var logoutPopup: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var homeTblView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //append colors

    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0xdd191d))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0xd81b60))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x8e24aa))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x5e35b1))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x3949ab))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x4e6cef))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x00acc1))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x00897b))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x0a8f08))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x7cb342))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0xc0ca33))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0xfdd835))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0xfb8c00))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0xf4511e))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0xf4511e))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x757575))
    colorList.append(UIColor(rgb: 0x546e7a))

    self.homeTblView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")
    self.homeTblView.register(UINib(nibName: "Home1Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Home1Cell")
    self.post_CouponsData()
    self.homeTblView.reloadData()
    print(selectedIds)

}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

func changeDateForamte(dateString: String, currentDateFormate: String, newDateFormate: String) -> String
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = currentDateFormate
    let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = newDateFormate
    return  dateFormatter.string(from: newDate!)
}

@IBAction func logout_yes(_ sender: Any) {
   let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func logout_no(_ sender: Any) {
   self.logoutPopup.removeFromSuperview()
}

@objc func openDeals(sender: UIButton) {
    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: couponsData[sender.tag].guid!)!)
    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: IBActions
@IBAction func toCategoryScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

@IBAction func toSearchPage(_ sender: UIButtonX) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPageController") as! SearchPageController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func logoutBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.AddSubViewtoParentView(parentview: self.view, subview: logoutPopup)
}

func post_CouponsData() {
    if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {

        var params = [String : String]()

        params ["term_ids"] = "\(self.selectedIds.map(String.init).joined(separator: ","))"

        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)

        APIClient<ModelBaseCouponsList>().API_POST(Url: SD_POST_CouponsList, Params: params as [String:AnyObject], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

            if(modelResponse.success == true) {

                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

                let dict = modelResponse.coupons
                for i in dict! {
                    self.couponsData.append(i)
                }

            }else {
                self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
            }
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.homeTblView.reloadData()

        }) { (failed) in
            self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
        }
    }else {
        self.view.makeToast("No internet connection...")
        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
    }
}
```

}

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return couponsData.count
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if !couponsData[indexPath.row].postImage!.isEmpty {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
        let dict = couponsData[indexPath.row]

        if let postTitle = dict.postTitle, postTitle.count != 0 {
            cell.ticket_postTitle.text = postTitle
        }
        if let postContent = dict.postContent, postContent.count != 0 {
            cell.ticket_postContent.text = postContent
        }
        if let storeName = dict.stores, storeName.count != 0 {
            cell.storename.text = storeName
        }

        cell.home_image.image = UIImage(named: dict.postImage!)
        cell.ticketImageView.tintColor = colorList[indexPath.row]
        cell.ticket_ValidDate.text = self.changeDateForamte(dateString: dict.validTill!, currentDateFormate: "yyyy-MM-dd", newDateFormate: "dd MMMM yyyy")

        //        cell.ticketImageView.tintColor = .random()
        cell.goToDealBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.goToDealBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openDeals), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Home1Cell", for: indexPath) as! Home1Cell
        let dict = couponsData[indexPath.row]

        if let postTitle = dict.postTitle, postTitle.count != 0 {
            cell.ticket_postTitle.text = postTitle
        }
        if let postContent = dict.postContent, postContent.count != 0 {
            cell.ticket_postContent.text = postContent
        }
        if let storeName = dict.stores, storeName.count != 0 {
            cell.storename.text = storeName
        }

        cell.ticketImageView.tintColor = colorList[indexPath.row]
        cell.ticket_ValidDate.text = self.changeDateForamte(dateString: dict.validTill!, currentDateFormate: "yyyy-MM-dd", newDateFormate: "dd MMMM yyyy")

        //        cell.ticketImageView.tintColor = .random()
        cell.goToDealBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.goToDealBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openDeals), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if !couponsData[indexPath.row].postImage!.isEmpty {
       return 339.0
    }else {
        return 234.0
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if !couponsData[indexPath.row].postImage!.isEmpty {
        return 339.0
    }else {
        return 234.0
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is so much code. What's working, what's not working? What's your issue exactly?

Comment: hello sir..in my search controller searching data is coming but i want that when i click on search result data, it should go back to previous screen i.e home screen and reload data according to selected search text. and the search text is category and store data

Comment: Please help me with my problem

Comment: Can anyone help me with my problem?